# Why does 'Git add *' leave some files unstaged?

Tags: python, django, git, git-add

I initialized a new git repo in my Django project. All files( including the *files in subdirectories* and **pipfile**) are staged when I run **git add *** except the **.__atomic-writegxd2tirf** file. Why is this one excluded?

Comment: Run the command `echo *`. What file names are printed out? Why is `.__atomic-writegxd2tirf` not printed?

Comment: is there a gitignore file?

Comment: no there is no gitignore file @MohammadFaisal

Comment: @torek yes man, it's not printed, i don' know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **git add *** stages only the whose names do not begin with a **"."** hence the problem.
An alternate way could be running **git add .** for all files OR running **git add**  for the file name beginning with a **"."(dot)** exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have experienced this with several different commands (`git add` and `echo` in particular), it's time to generalize.

On Unix-like systems (including Linux, macOS Terminal windows, and so on), or when using `bash` as a command interpreter on Windows, you are dealing with a programming language that is called a *shell*.  There are different shell programming languages (bash, dash, sh, zsh, fish, and so on—most tend to have `sh` in their names for historical reasons) but they all tend to share certain attributes.  One of these is how they *expand* command line arguments to be passed to commands.

```
$ mkdir t && cd t && touch .a .b c d e
$ ls -A
.a      .b      c       d       e
$ echo *
c d e
```

There are five files<sup>1</sup> in this temporary directory (besides the standard two named `.` and `..` that `ls -A` omits).  But `echo *` only expands to three of them.  That's because `*` expansion deliberately *omits* any files whose name<sup>2</sup> *starts with `.`*.

Some shells have an option to turn this on or off: e.g., in bash, you can set the `dotglob` option.  (Users probably shouldn't fiddle with these options too much, lest they get surprises when using someone else's shell or some other shell, but it's good to know that they exist.)

Shell programming languages are mostly constructed around the idea of *running other programs*.  So when the shell produces a prompt, like `$` or `>` or whatever the shell's standard prompt is, and you type in a series of white-space-separated words, the shell breaks up those words and uses one of them as a command name and the rest as arguments to the command, and runs that command.  Hence, entering:

```
git add *
```

has the shell run the `git` command with arguments `add` and `*`.  But `*` itself is treated specially *by the shell*, expanded out to file names, excluding those that start with dot.  So the `git` command sees only the arguments:

```
add
c
d
e
```

(one argument per line).  The first argument to `git` is a sub-command, in this case `add`, and the remaining are interpreted by the sub-command.<sup>3</sup>

Since `*` got expanded by the shell, Git never *sees* the `*` and never has its own chance to do its own thing with the `*`.  You can, however, protect the `*` from the shell:

```
*
```

Here, the shell treated the double quotes as a sort of protection.  This kept the shell from interpreting the `*`.  The shell *did* interpret the double quotes themselves though, so `echo` did not see the double quotes.  It saw only the asterisk `*`.

```
$ echo '"*"'
"*"
```

This time I used single quotes as the outer layer.  These also tell the shell to protect stuff, i.e., not to interpret either the double quotes *or* the asterisk.  So this time `echo` saw both the double quotes and the asterisk.

The shells' rules for quoting vary from one shell to another, and this can all get very complicated.  None of this has anything to do with Git itself: the shell is doing the same kind of interpretation regardless of which command is to be run.

If you do manage to pass a literal asterisk on to Git, *Git* will do its own interpretation of the asterisk, and its interpretation differs from the shell's.  So `git add '*'` behaves differently.

If you use Windows and `CMD.EXE`, note that `CMD.EXE` itself is not nearly as programmable as a shell and has much simpler command-line rules.  In some ways this makes its use easier and more predictable.  This is its advantage, but also its disadvantage: the programmability of the typical Unix shells makes it possible to write entire systems using them.

---

<sup>1</sup>In the world of Unix, even a directory (or folder, if you prefer that term) is a kind of file.  Sometimes people use the word *file* to mean both files and directories, but since I've excluded `.` and `..`, which are directory-files, I bypassed the need to mention it—except for this footnote!

<sup>2</sup>In a hierarchical file system like those found on Unix-like systems, files don't necessarily have just one name.  Here, the word *name* really refers to a *component name* as found in some containing directory.  The file's name in Git might be `path/to/.file` for instance.  At the Unix-file-system level, however, this is a directory named `path` holding a directory named `to` holding a file whose component name is `.file`.  To the *shell* there's a dot in the part of the file name at the end, so `echo path/to/*` won't match it.

<sup>3</sup>This pattern of having a top level command with sub-commands has become more common recently, but only parts of the Unix system work this way.  In Python in particular you can use `argparse` to emulate this same kind of behavior.